# TableView cell returns nil, when overriding Swipe VC superclass in Category VC

Tags: swift, uitableview, model-view-controller, swipe

I got the "**Error: UITableView dataSource returned a nil cell for row at index path.**"
To-do list was working when I had the Swipe methods as an extension from CategoryVC. Then I moved the extension to its own SwipeVC file. I matched the prototype cell identifiers ("Cell") in storyboard. As you can see, I'm now trying to define cellForRow in SwipeVC, then override it ("super") in order to set its name property in CategoryVC.

```
class CategoryViewController: UIViewController {

let realm = try! Realm()
var catArray: Results<Category>?
```

CategoryVC DataSource methods:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return catArray?.count ?? 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = catArray?[indexPath.row].name ?? "no Cats yet"

    return cell
}
```

SwipeVC DataSource method:

```
class SwipeTableViewController: UITableViewController, SwipeTableViewCellDelegate 

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SwipeTableViewCell
        
    cell.delegate = self
       
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why is dequeueReusableCell commented out?

Comment: You define tableView delegate funcs in 2 classes ?

Comment: @PhillipMills returning ?? 1 will return one cell (that displays "no Cats yet") while 0 wouldn't display that text. Regardless, the code doesn't get that far.

Comment: @claude31 yes, once in SwipeVC to initialize and then in CategoryVC to override (with super to get superclass)

Comment: @StonedStudio because it's initialized in swipeVC

Comment: I'm going to guess the issue has something to do with how you separated the files out. - It's not entirely clear to me what it is you're trying to accomplish. But it sounds like you're trying to separate code and make a tableViewCell class, but created a whole new view controller instead.

Comment: @StonedStudio I think you're right! I'm trying another override, and it's not linking properly.

Comment: No problem. Hope it works.

Comment: @StonedStudio it works!! I reviewed all the setup. Category VC needed SwipeTableViewController as super, I had it backwards. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked out! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> It sounds like you're trying to separate code and make a tableViewCell class, but created a whole new view controller instead.

This means that CategoryVC and SwipeVC cannot communicate. The superclass for CategoryVC has to be SwipeTableViewController (not UIViewController) in order to override something in the other VC.